# SQL Server : LIMIT not working on complex query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a rather long and complex SQL query that I'm working on at the moment.

What I want to do is just add `LIMIT 10` ... But every time I end it to the end of the query I'm getting errors.

Any help would be amazing, the query is as follows:

```
sqlQuery = "
  select      DATENAME(Month,i.Datecreated) + ' ' + 
              DATENAME(day,i.Datecreated) + ' ' + 
              DATENAME(year,i.Datecreated) AS USDateCreated,
              i.imageId,
              GalleryName,Fullpath,MediumPath,ThumbPath,ViewCounter,
              i.DateCreated,ItemNumber,Gender,Minutes,
              right(convert(varchar(3), 100 + Seconds),2) as Seconds,
              FramesPerSecond,WeekNumber,Filename,
              (round(cast(Size as Decimal(16,2))/1024,2)) as Size,
              FlvFilename,FlvSize,NumberOfMovies,
              Free,Comment,
              (case when sum(rating)/count(i.imageId) is null then 0 else sum(rating)/count(i.imageId) end) as ratingResult, 
              dbo.getTagNames(i.imageid) as tagsname,'' as yourTagNames,
              dbo.getTagNames(i.imageid) as memberTagNames,max(weekNumber)-1 as lastWeek 

  from        images as i 

  left join   Imagerating as ir on i.imageId = ir.imageId

  left join   tag as t on i.imageId = t.imageId where 1=1 

  and         galleryName = 'pictures' 

  and         weekNumber = '4' 

  group by    i.imageId,GalleryName,Fullpath,MediumPath,ThumbPath,
              ViewCounter,i.DateCreated,ItemNumber,Gender,Minutes,Seconds,
              FramesPerSecond,WeekNumber,Filename,Size,FlvFilename,FlvSize,
              NumberOfMovies,Free,Comment 

  order by    filename
"
```

Comment: Try formatting it before debugging it.

Comment: what is the error you keep getting?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: http://vorg.ca/626-the-MS-SQL-equivalent-to-MySQLs-limit-command

Comment: LIMIT is MySql syntax. It won't work in Sql Server.

Comment: `LIMIT` is a proprietary, non-ANSI-standard extension that's available only in MySQL (as far as I know). Other RDBMS use other ways of limiting the number of rows returned - like `SELECT TOP (n)` or something like that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

T-SQL doesn't support `LIMIT`.  Instead, use [`TOP`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) in your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT TOP 100 -- Rather than LIMIT 100 at the bottom
    Field1, Field2 -- etc.
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Field1
ORDER BY Field2
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or greater you can use [`OFFSET` and `FETCH [FIRST|NEXT]`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) to get `LIMIT`'s ability to page through the result set.

Comment: Thanks @sean ... how do i select the next 100 after the first 100 ?

Comment: Using top 10 doesnt seem to work either, it keeps spitting out all the results

Comment: @BigJobbies - I updated my answer with T-SQL's equivalent to `LIMIT`

Answer (score 1):

In TSQL the function to use is TOP, not LIMIT:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Table
```

Comment: Thank you for that ... If i wanted to load the next 10 using a more button, how could i go about that though ... can i do top 10, 20 ?

Comment: Using top 10 doesnt seem to work either, it keeps spitting out all the results

Comment: Unfortunately is a little more complicated than that. Check out this post: http://joelabrahamsson.com/my-favorite-way-to-do-paging-with-t-sql/

Comment: Wow, that makes no sense to me hahaha ... Is there a way that i can use the same SQL statement but convert it to something that uses the LIMIT ?

Comment: If you're using sql server 2012 there seems to be a new set of functions: http://www.dbadiaries.com/new-t-sql-features-in-sql-server-2012-offset-and-fetch

Answer (score 1):

LIMIT doesn't work in Sql Server. It's a MySql proprietary extension to standard SQL. In Sql Server, you can use the simple `TOP n` for the first page, but that's not really a good choice either if you're trying to do pagination.

Fortunately, a more recent version of the SQL standard specifies a syntax you can use for pagination, and if you're lucky enough to be on Sql Server 2012 or later you can use it. It's called [OFFSET/FETCH](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx), and it looks something like this:

```
SELECT <columns> FROM <table> ORDER BY <order> OFFSET 30 ROWS FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY;
```

That would fetch the *3rd* page if the page size if 15. Note that the ORDER BY clause is required. Otherwise, an offset has no meaning. This is *standard sql*. Not only does Sql Server support it, but so does Oracle, PostGre, and a few others, and you can export more coming over time.